# different stylesheet for mobile devices

Tags: css, mobile, blogger

i am trying to make my blogger.com blog mobile friendly,i wrote a css that would do that ,now how do i make blogger swap the origional stylesheet and use the mobile version in case of it is accessed by a mobile deveice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **media="handheld"** attribute in the css link. http://www.htmldog.com/ptg/archives/000055.php.

Grz, Kris.